# Валидация на jQuery + codignater.

Tags: jquery, php

Мне необходимо сделать страничку регистрации на PHP (codeignater). После, необходимо подключить проверку формы при помощи jQuery. С php разобрался, вот на jQuery застрял. Все вроде понятно, только не могу собрать все воедино и выстроить в логическую цепь. Какие плагины подключать? Нужен ли Ajax? Помогите, чем можете, ребята!

Comment: Ajax нужен исключительно для проверки доступности логина, все остальное делается прямо на клиенте...

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки полей формы на стороне клиента, есть плагин `jQuery Validation`. Ну, а для понимания плагина  - [статья](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/46.html).